# Attach arbitrary data to jwplayer setup options

Tags: html, video, jwplayer

I want to be able to do the following:

```
jwplayer("myElement").setup({
    ...
    myoption: 'myvalue'
});
```

and then I would like to get the value of `myoption` in some way. For example:

```
jwplayer("myElement").options.myoption
```

Is it possible to do this?

PS. Don't ask me why I want to do this. I know that there are other ways. But I am asking about this way.

Comment: Hm, I have never seen a JW Player set up like this before, I doubt this is possible.